# Javascript test for existence of object key in a object with arrays which use values instead of index

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have been reading through many of the great code examples which test for the existence of object key in a object with arrays.  These are great...

My problem is the JSON returned has key value that must be used to get to the items inside the array. Here is an example.  Look at "orders":

```
{"Routes": [
     {
        "route": {
            "id": "1daf1f53-80b6-49d6-847a-0ee8b814e784-20180821"
        },
        "vehicle": {
            "id": "1daf1f53-80b6-49d6-847a-0ee8b814e784"
        },
        "driver": {
            "id": "6c2823be-374e-49e5-9d99-2c3f586fc093"
        },
        "orders": {
            "6df85e5f-c8bc-4290-a544-03d7895526b9": {
                "id": "6df85e5f-c8bc-4290-a544-03d7895526b9",
                "delivery": {
                    "customFields": {
                        "custom": "5379"
                    }
                },
                "isService": true
            }
         }    
   }
    ]
};
```

The code I am using works up to the point where I have to specify the key value:

```
function checkProperty(obj, prop) {
  var parts = prop.split('.');
  for (var i = 0, l = parts.length; i < l; i++) {
    var part = parts[i];
    if (obj !== null && typeof obj === "object" && part in obj) {
      obj = obj[part];
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  return true;
}
```

Here are some samples that work and fail:

```
console.log(checkProperty(test, 'Routes.0.orders'));  //Works returns true
console.log(checkProperty(test, 'Routes.0.orders.id'));  //Fails returns false
console.log(checkProperty(test, 'Routes.0.orders.6df85e5f-c8bc-4290-a544-03d7895526b9.id)); //Fails returns false
```

I am at my wits end and would appreciate any help...

Comment: You should have a look at the for...in instruction, which will make it possible to iterate through your orders values : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/for...in

Comment: You have a typo, there should be a `.` before `6df85e5f` in your last sample.

Comment: Why do you think the second sample should return `true`? `id` is not a direct child of `orders`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 "orders": {
            "6df85e5f-c8bc-4290-a544-03d7895526b9": {
                "id": "6df85e5f-c8bc-4290-a544-03d7895526b9"
```

second test:
    Id is not a direct child of "Orders" in your example: 
    orders.6df85e5f-c8bc-4290-a544-03d7895526b9.id

third test:
     syntax error in the third - missing '.'

Comment: Instead of just saying what's wrong, you should show how to solve the problem.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean "Id is not a child of orders"  to access the order detail I have to us the id value :

    myJSON.approvedRoutes[i].orders["6df85e5f-c8bc-4290-a544-03d7895526b9"]